# Reference type of HashMap in jsp:useBean

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I have a HashMap that I want to pass to my view but I'm not able to get the HashMap correctly with jsp:useBean. So here is how I construct my HashMap and put in scope request :

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HAVerification>> hash = d.getVerificationByWF(dem2);
request.setAttribute("hash", hash);
```

My HashMap has a String as key and an ArrayList of object HAVerification as value. Now I want to get this hash in my view so I tried with this jsp:useBean

```
<jsp:useBean id="hash" type="java.util.HashMap<String, Arraylist<HAVerification>>" scope="request"/>
```

But this doesn't work, I also tried with

```
<jsp:useBean id="hash" type="java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.util.List<servlet.HAVerification>>" scope="request"/>
```

And didn't work too

How can I do to reference the type of the HashMap ?

Comment: Why not accessing the hash attribute with expression language and forget about the Jsp tag?

Comment: @AngeloOparah It's ok, I've found an other solution

Comment: @SimonM. Please tell, what the solution you have found.